# Is the way of syllafibication certain?

Tags: syllables

How to syllabify may be certain in many words. But some words have several ways, I think.  For example, "extra" can be divided into "ek" + "stra" and "eks" + "tra". 
Does this mean that people remember a word in several different ways? Or do people usually have a fixed manner individually to utter a word which can be divided in several ways, with more easiness?

Comment: I don't know if it is universal for everyone, but one way or the other will feel more natural or be easier to say.  For me, the hard K is easier to say than the softer ks sound, and "stra" and "tra" are about equal.  So I pronounce it the first way.

Comment: And some people say it  *eks-ter-uh* or maybe that’s *ek-stir-uh*...

Comment: There are rules for phonological syllabification; for instance, if _extra_ were syllabified into eks.tra, the /t/ would be lightly aspirated, but if it is syllabified into ek.stra, the /t/ would be part of an initial cluster and couldn't be aspirated. There are lots of little clues like that in pronunciation; of course spelling messes it up here because the /ks/ cluster has only one letter in _extra_.